# Do Korean airlines still overfly Russia?

Tags: air-travel, russia

Do Korean airlines as Asiana and Korean Airlines on their way to or from Europe still overfly Russia ?

Comment: [flightradar24](https://www.flightradar24.com/) can be helpful..

Comment: Korean Airlines quite famously overflew Russia (then part of the USSR) twice in September 1983 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korean_Air_Lines_Flight_007).  That flight is a large part of the reason that GPS became a public system and not restricted to military use/

Comment: @NeanDerThal for example, https://www.flightradar24.com/data/flights/ay41#2cc74b80

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It doesn't look like Korean or Asiana overfly Russian airspace.

Korean airlines no longer flies over Russian airspace:[Link from Reuters](https://www.reuters.com/world/asia-pacific/korean-air-says-reroute-flights-that-used-russian-airspace-2022-03-15/)

I found similar articles for Asiana but in Korean only. In any case, all flights to Europe are avoiding Russian airspace as seen on flight trackers ([example Seoul-Frankfurt](https://www.flightradar24.com/data/flights/oz541))